# Nested inline-block element is pushed up in FF / IE when overflow is set to hidden

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

This doesn't occur in Chrome.  I am trying to implement an Ellipsis for the nested element.  Has anyone else come across this and, if so, were you able to work around?

```
<span>bar <span class="foo">foo</span> bar</span>

span.foo {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;        
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwZAX/6/)

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">bar <span class="foo">foo</span> bar</a>

span.foo {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;        
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwZAX/7/)

Comment: I had similar problem, try to change it to `display: inline;` this should solve your FF problems. Not really sure if it is the best solution for IE.

Comment: Meh, who cares about IE.  I have to use `display: inline-block` though or the ellipsis won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` where you have `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to [the specification on overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html), which works only on block element and how line-height work.

Your outer span is *by default* `display:inline`. **An inline element should not contains block elements**. Although, setting it to `display:block` won't fix the problem.

The problem is the baseline for the text (outer element) is the same for the **box** of the inner element. So the **box** sit at the same height it should start the text (which leave a bit of white space underneat).

Anyway, it might be easier to understand [with a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uwZAX/9/).

If you set the line-height of the inner-span to lower than the text actual height, the box will conserve its size. Of course thirtydot solution is also valid.